# Is there a better way to determine if computeIfAbsent returned a new value?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I've got code like this :

```
ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
AtomicBoolean isNew = new AtomicBoolean(false);
String result = map.computeIfAbsent("foo", key -> {
    isNew.set(true);
    return "bar";
});
result = result + "common op that occurs on both old and new results";
if (isNew.get()) {
    // op that occurs only on new results.  Must occur after common op.
}
```

Is there a prettier way to do this given that my compute method is heavy enough that I don't want to create and the immediately discard computed values if they aren't needed?

Edit: I'm also worried how well my code will cope with threading.  If 2 threads try to compute for the same key I think they might both end up reporting true for isNew.

Comment: It would be helpful if the JDK provided a `putIfAbsent` method that receives a lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

You could just have the logic in the `computeIfAbsent` lambda - it will only be executed if a new value has to be computed:

```java
String result = map.computeIfAbsent("foo", key -> {
    // do special stuff here
    return "bar";
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the response.  In my case the 'special stuff' needs to happen after an operation that occurs on result.  I could include this operation in the lamda as well, but then I'd need a way to make the operation not happen when the lamda runs.  Either way I end up needing a var on the outside.